# Qt - Detect when QWindow is closed

Tags: c++, qt, game-engine

I'm making a game with Qt, and I'm making a custom game loop so I can precisely control the logic timestep and render at a maximum frame rate.

Normally, to create a `QWindow` you would do this:

```
...
QGuiApplication app(argc,argv);
QWindow* window = new QWindow();
window.show();
app.exec();
...
```

And `exec()` would return when the window is closed.

However, I'm doing it the following way:

```
QGuiApplication *app = new QGuiApplication(argc,argv);
     QWindow* window = new QWindow();
     window.show();
     while (!terminate_loop) {
          app->processEvents();
          GameUpdate();
          GameRender();
     }
     app->exit();
```

However, my loop keeps going when the window is closed. I need to detect when the window is closed so my loop can terminate. I've tried the following In order to capture when the window has been closed:

```
connect(app,SIGNAL(lastWindowClosed()),this,SLOT(windowClosed()));
```

he following slot should be fired when the window is closed, but it never gets fired. It **does** fire when I use `app->exec()`instead of manually processing events.

```
void QTEngine::windowClosed() {
    terminate_loop = true;
}
```

Upon further investigation, the Qt Documentation says the following:

> [lastWindowClosed] is emitted from exec() when the last visible primary
>   window (i.e. window with no parent) is closed.

Since I'm not using `exec()`, this signal is not being emitted. Is there any other way of detecting when the QWindow has been closed?

Answer (score 4):

You should probably use Qt internal event loop to design your game application. The ["OpenGL Window" example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgui-openglwindow-example.html) provided with Qt shows a good example of a rendering loop.

However, it is possible to get the close event on QWindow. The convenient closeEvent() function is not provided as of version 5.4.1. But, you can install an event filter object on a QWindow and grab the close event. Here is an example of such event filter object implementation:

```
class CloseEventFilter : public QObject
{
     Q_OBJECT
public:
     CloseEventFilter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent) {}

protected: 
     bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
     {
          if (event->type() == QEvent::Close)
          { 
               // Do something interesting, emit a signal for instance.
          }

          return QObject::eventFilter(obj, event);
     }

};
```

To attach your event filter to your window, you simply have to use the installEventFilter() function implemented by any QObject subclass, including QWindow.

```
QGuiApplication *app = new QGuiApplication(argc,argv);
QWindow* window = new QWindow();
CloseEventFilter *closeFilter = new CloseEventFilter(window);
window->installEventFilter(closeFilter);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it my `QQuickItem`:

```
  connect(
    this,
    &QQuickItem::windowChanged,
    this,
    [this](QQuickWindow* const w)
    {
      if (w)
      {
        connect(
          w,
          &QWindow::visibleChanged,
          this,
          [this](bool const v)
          {
            if (!v)
            {
              // window closing
            }
          }
        );
      }
    },
    Qt::DirectConnection
  );
```

`close()` can either hide your window or destroy it. Depending on what it does, you need to connect to either `&QWindow::visibleChanged` or `&QObject::destroyed`.

Answer (score -1):

I can think of two possible solutions off the top of my head. I have not tested either of the solutions.

1) You could create your `QWindow` with the `Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose` flag. What this does is it deletes the object when the window is closed. Any `QObject` that is deleted emits the `destroyed()` signal, which means you should be able to connect the `destroyed()` signal to your slot.

2) You could also re-implement the `QWidget::closeEvent()` handler of your `QWindow`, and emit your own custom signal.

Comment: AFAIK you can't set Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose on a QWindow instance, only on a QWidget instance

Comment: Neither solution apply to QWindow, since it does not derive from QWidget.